# ¿Acceder a un array dentro de un objeto y extraer una propiedad?

Tags: array, reactjs, object, objeto, map

Se que es una pregunta bastante básica, pero mi nivel es este. La cuestión es que sé que es algo no muy difícil pero no caigo, y por más que busco no encuentro lo que yo exáctamente quiero hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el arbol de propiedades del objeto de la API de pokemon. Quiero hacerme una pokédex e ir sacando propiedades para añadirlas a una ficha de pokemon. Ya he podido acceder como pueden ver a `name` y a `id`, y ahora quiero acceder a `abilities`. Creo recordar que era usando `.map()`, pero no se bien como hacerlo. El tema es que quiero acceder a **abilities > 0 > ability > name**, para que diréctamente por la pantalla se muestre el **"static"**.

Es usando `Array.map()`? Hay alguna otra forma más ordenada y correcta? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Usa el .map en el array que te proporciona abilities, con esto iras recorriendo todas las posiciones del array y podrás extraer la información que necesitas.

Comment: Funcionó. Sabía yo que tenía que ver con map. Al final puse un condicional: map( (curr, ind) => { if ( ind === 0) {return curr.ability.name} E igual para el caso del index cuando sea 1. Gracias por vuestra ayuda, un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

hace tiempo yo realice algo similar lo que hice fue obtener el elemento con jQuery seria algo como  
 
let name = $(this).data.abilities[0].ability.name; 
console.log(name); 
 no recuerdo si al final va con paréntesis (), el this referencia el elemento ya seleccionado pero en mi caso el elemento que ocupe tenia un evento por eso lo ocupe de esa manera. espero responder tu pregunta y si no ser guía para ella.

Comment: Genial. Me quedaré con este comentario que me dejas. Al final, como digo por ahí arriba, me funcionó con el map, pero tendré en cuenta tu consejo. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, las habilidades te  las proprciona la API como un arreglo de objetos, lo primero es entender que forma tiene el JSON, por lo visto la propiedad abilities se encuentra en la raíz de la respuesta que te devuelve axios, abilities es un arreglo de objetos, donde cada objeto contiene a su tres propiedades, de las cuales la que te interesa es a su vez otro objeto de nombre ability, que tiene dos propiedades, de las cuales la que te interesa se llama name:

```
    data: 
         |_abilitiesObjectArray:
                                |_abilityObject:
                                                |_ability:
                                                          |_name: valor
```

El método `map` retornará un nuevo arreglo, cuyos elementos serán retornados a su vez por una función que recibe como argumento y que se ejecutará por cada elemento del arreglo original. Esta función parámetro recibirá como entrada cada valor del arreglo original.

```
const {abilities} = data; //ObjectArray
const abilitiesStringArray = abilities.map( abilityObject => { return abilityObject.ability.name } );
```

[image: Output]

Te dejo el siguiente link para mas detalles

[MDN - Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)

Suerte

Comment: Funcionó. Sabía yo que tenía que ver con map. Al final puse un condicional:

`map( (curr, ind) => {
if ( ind === 0) {return curr.ability.name}`

E igual para el caso del index cuando sea 1. Gracias por vuestra ayuda, un saludo!